# flycheck-haskell and doctest don't work on Cabal 3.0 v2-build project

Tags: haskell, cabal

I tried to create a Nix-style local build (v2-build) project on Cabal 3.0.
But several development tools (flycheck-haskell and doctest) don't work.
They worked on new-build project on Cabal 2.4.
Error message says they cannot find dependencies, as far as I read.

```
$ cabal v2-clean
$ cabal v2-build
$ cabal v2-test
Build profile: -w ghc-8.8.1 -O1
In order, the following will be built (use -v for more details):
 - hstest9-0.1.0.0 (test:doctestd) (first run)
Configuring test suite 'doctestd' for hstest9-0.1.0.0..
Preprocessing test suite 'doctestd' for hstest9-0.1.0.0..
Building test suite 'doctestd' for hstest9-0.1.0.0..
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test/doctest-driver.hs, /Users/user/work/hstest9/dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.8.1/hstest9-0.1.0.0/t/doctestd/build/doctestd/doctestd-tmp/Main.o )
Linking /Users/user/work/hstest9/dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.8.1/hstest9-0.1.0.0/t/doctestd/build/doctestd/doctestd ...
Running 1 test suites...
Test suite doctestd: RUNNING...

/Users/user/work/hstest9/src/MyLib.hs:3:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Control.Effect’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
3 | import Control.Effect
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Test suite doctestd: FAIL
Test suite logged to:
/Users/user/work/hstest9/dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.8.1/hstest9-0.1.0.0/t/doctestd/test/hstest9-0.1.0.0-doctestd.log
0 of 1 test suites (0 of 1 test cases) passed.
cabal: Tests failed for test:doctestd from hstest9-0.1.0.0.
```

Answer (score 5):

Your doctest doesn't find proper [GHC_ENVIRONEMNT](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/packages.html#envvar-GHC_ENVIRONMENT).

Since Cabal 3.0, cabal v2-build doesn't generate environment files by default.

> Since Cabal 3.0, defaults to never. Before that, defaulted to creating them only when compiling with GHC 8.4.4 and older (GHC 8.4.4 is the first version that supports the -package-env - option that allows ignoring the package environment files).
>   https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/nix-local-build.html#cfg-field-write-ghc-environment-files

So you should set this option on v2-build.

```
$ cabal v2-build --write-ghc-environment-files=ghc8.4.4+
```

Or you can write this in [$HOME/.cabal/config](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/installing-packages.html#overview) for default cabal behavior.

```
write-ghc-environment-files: ghc8.4.4+
```